# How to display a row count result in twig file

Tags: mysql, symfony, twig

I am fetching a row count inside a repository and that query is returning an array as a result. How do i fetch the number count and display the result in my twig file?

This is the query fetching row count:

```
public function getTrailCount(){

    $sql = "SELECT count(`id`)  FROM `article` where `publish`='1' AND `catForFilter` like '%trail%' ";

    $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $trailCount = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    //$trailCount->getSingleScalarResult();

    //echo '<pre>'; print_r($trailCount); exit;

    return $trailCount;
}
```

In controller i am trying to fetch it like this, i know its a wrong procedure though:

```
foreach($trailCount as $trail){

        $data['trailCount'] = $trail->count; //throughing an error

    }
```

How to mend this code, any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, using `PDO::FETCH_NUM` would be much simpler:

```
$trailCount = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
...
foreach($trailCount as $trail){
    $data['trailCount'] = $trail[0]; // Using "0" instead of named key
}
```

But if you still really want to use `FETCH_ASSOC` you would need:

```
$sql = "SELECT count(`id`) as cnt  FROM `article ...... "
.....

foreach($trailCount as $trail){
    $data['trailCount'] = $trail['cnt'];
}
```

Notice that I'm not using `->cnt` but `['cnt']` since data returned from `PDO` is not object-based but array-bases instead.

Hope this helps a bit...

### EDIT:

Given the lack of `Twig` part, I can only assume what you're trying to do:

```
/**
 * @Route("/foo")
 * @Template()
 */
public function fooAction(){
    ...
    ... The code above
    ...

    return array('data' => $data);
}
```

And then, in your twig:

```
{{ data.trailCount }}
```

Comment: Can you please clarity? Please update the question with some relevant `twig` part...

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution with some help of Jovan Perovic, i did like this:

The query Part:

```
public function getTrailCount(){

$sql = "SELECT count(`id`) as cnt  FROM `article` where `publish`='1' AND `catForFilter` like '%trail%' ";

$stmt = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$trailCount = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

return $trailCount[0]['cnt']; //instead of an array i passed the single value
}
```

in controller:

```
$trailCount = $clicknblog->getTrailCount();
return $this->render('AdventureBiddingBundle:Organiser:editProfileOrganiser.html.twig', array(                   
                'trails' => $trailCount

            ));
```

in twig file i displayed the value directly:

```
<p>{{ trails }}</p>
```

Hope this helps to someone with same problem

Comment: I believe that `$trailCount[0]['cnt']` will not work unless you define an alias named `cnt`...

Comment: ohh yes...sorry a typo was there. thanx for correction